# $(\prod_{i\in I}X_i, \mathcal{T}_p)$ is metrizable iff $X_i$ is metrizable and all $X_i$ is singleton set except countable many indices.

Tags: general-topology, metrizability

Note that $X_i$ is nonempty.

I guess that a singleton space as a factor of the product topology doesn't affect the whole product.

But I don't know how to show that in detial.

Just some hints are what I want.

Comment: First, note that the "only if" is not true because we might have $X_i = \varnothing$ for some $i$.

Comment: Also, please provide more details i.e. what direction you are struggling with.

Comment: @j3M Sorry, I have forgot that $X_i$ is nonempty. For "only if", I want to show that the product of uncountable sets that contain more than one points is not metrizable, and what confuses me is how to prove that there isn't any metric on it.

Comment: @PumpKin Are you familiar with the notion of first countability?

Comment: @j3M Yeah. I have just learned it.

Comment: I think your statement "there is no metric on an uncountable product" is false. But this metric will not generate the product topology.

Comment: As @j3M said, the solution is the first countability notion. As every metric space is first countable, show that if all $X_i$ have at least two elements and are metrizable, the product topology is not first countable, thus non metrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, it seems that you are asking why the product of unaccountably many spaces of cardinality at least then $2$ is not metrizable.

Let $X = \prod_iX_i$ a product of uncountably many metric spaces with the induced topology, all of size at least $2$. If $X$ is metrizable, then it is first countable.

Let $(x_i)_i \in X$ be any point, and $\{U^n\}_{n<\omega}$ a countable set of open neighborhoods of $(x_i)_i$. Then for every $n$ we have some basic open $\prod_i U_i^n \subset U^n$. In particular (by definition), $U_i^n = X_i$ for all but finitely many $i\in I$. Let $J = \{i\in I: \ \exists $n$ \, U_i^n\neq X_i \}$.

Can you prove $J$ is countable (and hence there is some $i_0\in I \smallsetminus J$)? Can you use that together with the fact that $X_{i_0}$ is metric with at least two pints, to find a neighborhood of $(x_i)_i$ that does not contain any of the $U^n$?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I have solved it. If $X$ is first countable, according to the definition, every neighborhood of $(x_i)_i$ should contain at least one $U^n$. This is where the contradiction occurs. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You are welcome!